# A question about function on product spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ be a family of topological spaces. Is the function $f$ from $X=\prod\{X_i:i\in I\}$ to $X_K=\prod\{X_k:k\in K\}$, Where $K$ is a finite subset of $I$, continuous and open?

The finiteness of set $K$ is influence to the answer of this question?

**Edit**: $f$ is the projection.

Comment: Surely it must depend on the choice of function? If one reduces your question to the case of a single topological space then you have asked: *Let $f : X \to X$ be a function. Is $f$ continuous and open?*

Comment: @FlybyNight: $f$ is the projection. sorry for the ambiguity in the question.

Comment: Presumably you mean to have the product topology on both $X, X_K$. Then $U$ is open in $X_K$ **iff** $U$ has the form $U=\Pi_{i \in K} U_i$ where each $U_i$ is open in $X_i$. It follows that $f^{-1} U$ is open in the product (or box, for that matter since it is finer) topology on $X$.

Comment: @copper.hat: not each open set has this form. I assume you mean basis set.

Comment: @StefanH.: Good catch, that was sloppy of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the openness of $f:\prod_IX_i\to\prod_K X_k,\ p_k(f(\langle x_i\rangle_i))=x_k$ it suffices to show that for a non-empty basic open set, that is a product $B=\prod_I U_i$ where each $\emptyset\ne U_i\subseteq X_i$ is open and $U_i\ne X_i$ only for finitely many $i\in I$, the image $f(B)$ is open. But how can you write this image as a product?

The continuity of $f$ is obvious since $f$ is continuous iff $p_k\circ f$ is continuous for each $k\in K.$

Note that $K$ can be any subset of $I.$